# Delete, Create and Add Nodes to Index Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

A quick question.
In a single transaction, can't I do the followings:

1. Delete index say `indexMaster` if already exists
2. Create index again `indexMaster`
3. Add nodes to index `indexMaster`

`

When I did the above things I got exception.

```
This index (Index[indexMaster,Node]) has been marked as deleted in this transaction
```

This exception occurs at line on which I am adding nodes to it.

EDITED:
I am using Neo4j 2.0.4
Code using Java not REST API

Any Idea
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure here but I guess it is not possible to delete and recreate the same index in the same transaction. Try to use two transactions, one for deleting the index, the other for creating it.

Comment: Yeah, Micheal Hunger also told me the same.. I think it is not possible to  delete and create index in same transaction as I was getting exception 'This Index is marked as deleted in this transaction'